# Have problems in filtering binding source

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a datagridview and it's source is a bindingSource. I filter them by Id, name and date.
[image]

Also have clear button for clearing filters.

```
private void b_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_filterNum.Clear();
        txt_filterName.Clear();
        if (File.Exists(inputpath))
        {
            //MyLoad();
            bindingSource1.Filter = string.Empty;
            timeFilter.CustomFormat = " ";
            timeFilter.Text = null;
            timeFilter.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            gridFilter.Update();
            gridFilter.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

I'm having a really hard time filtering this gridview and clearing the filters.
Here I add my filter too.

```
 bindingSource1.Filter = $"Flight_Date = #{timeFilter.Value:M/dd/yyyy}# AND {gridFilter.Columns[indexRoleName].HeaderText} LIKE '%{txt_filterName.Text}%' AND {gridFilter.Columns[indexRoleNum].HeaderText} LIKE '%{txt_filterNum.Text}%'";
```

I call it in textboxes_changed and datetimePicker_valuechanged.

I can't filter the values properly, When I try to delete the filtering I have done, I can not get a reset in the datagridview.

Comment: Why are you changing the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`? I told you in your other question that all you need to do is set the `Filter` property and that's it. If you want to clear the filter, you simply set the `Filter` property to `Nothing` or `String.Empty`.

Comment: @John  bindingsource1.filter = string.empty; is it right?

Comment: You never need to ask us things that you can test for yourself and you never should. You also never need to ask us something that we literally just told you.

Comment: @John I tried but the clear function didnt help me to get the table as no filtered. I added the code of clear function. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the DataSource of the BindingSource? Note the `.HeaderText` property does not return the data source field. Replace it with [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).